# Mais como pronome indefinido ou advérbio?

Tags: gramática, pronomes, advérbios

Na frase

> A fragmentação do grupo rebelde criou o que a agência antidrogas da ONU descreve como um "mercado livre", **mais** competitivo, diversificado e compartimentado. Nesse processo, a América Central entrou no circuito.

O **mais** é pronome indefinido ou advérbio alterando o adjetivo "competitivo"?

Comment: Pronome? Como poderia ser um pronome, se não tem função de nome? Considero que aí a função é de advérbio mesmo.

Comment: Seria um pronome indefinido, como está previsto no dicionário: "determinante e pronome indefinido de dois géneros e dois números".

Answer (score 1):

*Mais* [pode ser pronome](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/pronome.htm), mas é um uso bastante raro; você basicamente só vai encontrar isso no dicionário. O pronome indefinido *demais* é menos incomum e tem uso semelhante.

No texto apresentado na pergunta, *mais* é um advérbio que está qualificando os adjetivos *competitivo*, *diversificado* e *compartimentado*.